# phaser - how to keep game data organized right way

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

My game will handle a data model like this:

```
- Characters
  - Name
  - PowerBase
- League
  - Title
  - BossName
- Match
  - Player
  - Character
  - League
  - Progress
  - PowerTotal
  - Money
    - Loan1, Loan2
    - Funding1, Funding2
```

As you can see, it's a nested data.

So, how should I handle this data between **registry update events**, **local storage** and **game scenes**?

Option 1) Keep everything in a single class with nested properties. It's a problem because `registry events` will not fire for specific properties.

Option 2) Keep a single variable for each data, with is hard to handle since they'll not be nested in classes.

Option 3) Any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your preference and usage. I personally like to use a global variable, that holds the entire gamestate. Using this method you have access from every scene without having to pass it.

And more over I don't use a class, I would simply use a json object, since they are easy to store if needed *(I try to keep the datastore as dumb as possible)*. But if you need more logic and actions, this might not be the best solution.

```js
// in the global scope 
const GAME_STATE_KEY = 'MY_GAME_STATE';
var GameState = {
    // ...
};

// functions to save and load the State (if you want to persist it)

function loadStateData(){
    GameState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(GAME_STATE_KEY));
}

function saveStateData(){
    localStorage.setItem(GAME_STATE_KEY, JSON.stringify(GameState));
}
```